# MVC windows authentication - user claims deny admin access: target .net4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

Im confused by windows Authentication on a site and how the claims for built in admin are managed.  A user that has Admin rights, but fails the `IsInRole(BuiltInAdmin)` test.

- Why was the deny claim allocated ?
- Should I be checking the user directly and not relying on the claims provided.?
- Is this an outcome on the NON Elevated identity claims using windows auth on the site?

The process was working all as expected until i added an IS admin check for certain cases.
I have used custom AUTH attribute which is triggered as expected
[Works as expected and documented AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
And I can return true or false. So thats all good.

**BUT check for ADMIN role fails.**

The CODE:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)] // all controllers inherit this attribuet
public class CUSTOMAuth:AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (! base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)) {
            return false;
        }
        // is the identity on teh request an admin ?
        return (IsLocalAdmin(httpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity));
    }
}


    public static bool IsLocalAdmin(WindowsIdentity identity) {
        var localAdmins = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
        if (identity != null) {
            var prin = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            return (prin.IsInRole(localAdmins));  //<<< returns false
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In debugger i see that httpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity was delivered with the 
CLAIMS/denyonlysid:

So that means the request is saying Except built in admin claims.
Although user Does have admin rights.

**EXTRA INFO:**
The APP POOL uses integrated mode.Windows Authentication,and Has a special user Identity.
The custom user does NOT have admin rights.

[image]

Comment: Should you be looking for a domain admin role?  Is built-in looking at the machine's local admin accounts?

Comment: thanks for the idea...I did already check against Local and domain admin roles. Same result.  The denyClaim is the issue.